# Create JIRA issue for TeamCity build failures

Tags: teamcity, jira

Does anyone know how to setup TeamCity so that it would create a new JIRA issue for each build breakage/failure?

We are trying to categorize/track/get-stats on our build breakages and need some kind of db.  JIRA would most likely do the job.

Answer (score 0):

If you can configure TeamCity to emit an email on failure, you can add issues in Jira via email.